# More concise/efficient regex to match a string within matching parentheses

Tags: regex

I would like to match strings, where `foo` appears within `select([...])`, but only if possibly occurring parentheses match together. E.g. match `select(((foo)))` or `select(x(())(foo(x))()x((y)x)x())` but not `select((foo)` or `select(x(foo)y()`.

I know, I have to limit the maximum number of nested parentheses and I came up with the following regular expression to solve the problem for one additional pair of parentheses:

```
select\((?:
    (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*
    foo
    (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*
    |
    (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*
    \([^()]*foo[^()]*\)
    (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*
)\)
```

That means that within `select([...])` **either** match `foo` with no or one pair of parentheses in front or behind **or** match `foo` within one pair of parentheses and with no or one pair of parentheses in front or behind.

Does anyone have a neater solution for this?

Expanding my regex to solve the problem for two additional pair of parentheses would look like this:

```
select\((?:
    (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\((?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)[^()]*)*
    foo
    (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\((?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)[^()]*)*
    |
    (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\((?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)[^()]*)*
    \((?:
        (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*
        foo
        (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*
        |
        (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*
        \([^()]*foo[^()]*\)
        (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*
    )\)
    (?:[^()]*|[^()]*\((?:[^()]*|[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)[^()]*)*
)\)
```

Whereby the most indented part is basically the previous regex and the `no or one pair of parentheses` parts have been expanded to `no or one or two pair of parentheses`.

I put this last regex on regex101: https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/1

The problem is that this regex (and even more further expanded versions) is quite time-consuming, so I'm hoping for better ideas.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple parser? Regex is the wrong tool to match nested languages.

Comment: What regex implementation are you using, what features does it support?

Comment: I want to search within files. Normally I use Notepad++, Eclipse or grepWin. AFAIK look around expressions are allowed there, but conditionals are not. But there may be search tools that allow conditional regex, so if needed, feel free to use conditionals (I don't know them well).

Comment: If you are interested by: https://regex101.com/r/nX2jM3/5

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you should do to simplify (and speed up) your regex:

- `(?: [^()]* | [^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]* )*` is an example of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). The outer, repeated group should only have two alternatives: a sequence of non-parenthesised characters or such a sequence between parenthesis:

  ```
  (?: [^()]+ | \([^()]*\) )*
  ```

  You were mixing the non-parenthesised characters `[^()]*` into both alternatives.
- Instead of doing `…foo…|…\(foo\)…`, you better should do `…(?:foo|\(foo\))…` so that you don't have to repeat the lengthy `…` thing.

With those two, your smaller expression becomes

```
select\(
(?: [^()]+ | \([^()]*\) )*
(?: foo | \([^()]*foo[^()]*\) )
(?: [^()]+ | \([^()]*\) )*
\)
```

I'll leave applying these onto the larger expression to you.

Comment: Very fast and very helpful answer, thank you! interestingly, fixing the catastrophic backtracking part improved the number of needed steps much less, than reducing the repetitions of the lengthy thing did. Pulling the lengthy things out of the OR part is quite obvious, apparently I didn't see the wood for the trees ;-)

Applying the expanded version of your suggestion to my regex101 examples reduced the number of steps from 25'548 to 514!

Unfortunately trying even the non-expanded version with Eclipse search does not come to an end, so I'm still hoping for more ideas/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html):

> If you want a regex that does not find any matches in a string that
>   contains unbalanced parentheses, then you need to use a [subroutine
>   call](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) instead of recursion.

I have tried to adapt a regex on that site for your needs:

```
(?im)^(?![^()]*\(\))[^()\n]*+(\((?>[^()\n]|(?1))*+\)[^()\n]*)++$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oO7qP4/1)

You can use this regex in [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), unfortunately, it does not work in Notepad++.

**To enforce a requirement of *match must begin with `select(`***, contain `foo` and end with `)`,  you just need to add a `(?=select\(.*foo.*\)$)` positive look-ahead in the beginning:

```
^(?=select\(.*foo.*\)$)(?![^()]*\(\))[^()\n]*+(\((?>[^()\n]|(?1))*+\)[^()\n]*)++$
```

See [updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/oO7qP4/3)

**.NET regex solution**

You may use a balanced + conditional constructs with a .NET regex (say, for use with `grepWin`):

```
select\((?>(?<f>foo)|[^()]|(?<o>)\(|(?<-o>)\))*(?(o)(?!))(?(f)|(?!))\)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=select%5C%28%28%3F%3E%28%3F%3Cf%3Efoo%29%7C%5B%5E%28%29%5D%7C%28%3F%3Co%3E%29%5C%28%7C%28%3F%3C-o%3E%29%5C%29%29*%28%3F%28o%29%28%3F!%29%29%28%3F%28f%29%7C%28%3F!%29%29%5C%29&i=select%28%28%28foo%29%29%29%20%0D%0Aselect%28x%28%28%29%29%28foo%28x%29%29%28%29x%28%28y%29x%29x%28%29%29%20%0D%0Abut%20not%0D%0Aselect%28%28fo%29%29%20%0D%0Aselect%28%28foo%29%20%0D%0Aselect%28x%28foo%29y%28%29). As you see, `select(((foo)))` and `select(x(())(foo(x))()x((y)x)x())` are matched, but `select((fo))` (no `foo`) and `select((foo)` (no matching parentheses) are not.

**Details**

- `select\(` - a `select(` substring
- `(?>` - start of an atomic group:

  - `(?<f>foo)|` - Group "f": a `foo` string, or
  - `[^()]|` - any char but `(` and `)`, or
  - `(?<o>)\(|` - a `(` char, and an empty string pushed on to Group "o" stack
  - `(?<-o>)\)`
- `)*` - end of the atomic group, 0 or more repetitions
- `(?(o)(?!))` - the first conditional construct: if Group "o" stack is not empty, fail the match (nested parantheses check)
- `(?(f)|(?!))` - the second conditional construct: if Group "f" stack is empty, fail the match (if "foo" is not present, when `foo` is present, Group "f" stack is not empty)
- `\)` - a `)` char

Comment: I hope this is helpful since you wrote in a comment that *there may be search tools that allow conditional regex, so if needed, feel free to use conditionals (I don't know them well).*

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, very interesting. Unfortunately your regex matches too much for my needs. The match must begin with `select(`, contain `foo` and end with `)`. I updated the test strings here: https://regex101.com/r/oO7qP4/2

I also tried to adapt your regex to satisfy these added test strings but without success :-( With you being more skilled with those advanced regex features, do you have an idea how to adjust the regex accordingly?

Comment: I updated the answer, you just need to add a positive look-ahead in the beginning to set this constraint.

Comment: Oh, this usage of look-ahead is nifty, thank you! I will try this solution with Sublime Text.

Comment: Using the regex with Sublime Text works very well (efficient), but doing so I found some more false positives, which got into the mix with the look-ahead (since the look-ahead does not check for balanced parentheses). I added a test case in version 5 (https://regex101.com/r/oO7qP4/5). Also I tried to allow multi-line matches, which I saved as version 6 (https://regex101.com/r/oO7qP4/6 ...I might have added some redundancy, though). Do you have any idea how can I get rid of these false positives?

Comment: The requirements are too complex now for a regex solution, the best I could write is `^(?=select(?=.*foo.*$)(\((?>[^()]|(?1))*+\))$)(?![^()]*\(\))[^()]*+(\((?>[^()]|(?2))*+\)[^()\n]*)++$`. Still, [matches 1 false positive](https://regex101.com/r/oO7qP4/7). It is becoming very difficult when a string spans across multiple lines.

Comment: Although I could eliminate all newlines in the files, I suspect it would still be very difficult to differentiate e.g. between `select(foo).from(bar).where(x)` (matching `select(foo)`) and `select(bar).from(foo).where(x)` (no match since "foo" is outside `select([...])`). The main difficulty seems to be bringing together the two requirements "contains foo" and "within balanced parentheses". The look-ahead does not require "foo" to appear within balanced parentheses and the main regex does not require "foo". Still, thanks a lot for your effort, I've learned some interesting things after all.

Comment: If I myself find an answer I will come back here.

Comment: @msa I added a .NET regex solution. It might help in tools that are based on .NET regex.